# hadoop word count example

Tags: hadoop, word-count

i am new to hadoop and i just installed hadoop 2.6.

its seems that the system started ok. i am trying to run the word count exmaple and ht e problem is that everthing seems to run , the output folder was created with 2 files:

-rw-r--r--   1 yoni supergroup          0 2016-04-30 02:11 /user/yoni/output100/_SUCCESS
-rw-r--r--   1 yoni supergroup          0 2016-04-30 02:11 /user/yoni/output100/part-r-00000

but the file is empty part-r-00000. the problem is i don't know were to look to find the problem,

this is the log of the job:

```
16/04/30 20:30:33 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
16/04/30 20:30:34 WARN mapreduce.JobSubmitter: No job jar file set.  User classes may not be found. See Job or Job#setJar(String).
16/04/30 20:30:34 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
16/04/30 20:30:34 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:1
16/04/30 20:30:34 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1461971181442_0005
16/04/30 20:30:34 INFO mapred.YARNRunner: Job jar is not present. Not adding any jar to the list of resources.
16/04/30 20:30:34 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1461971181442_0005
16/04/30 20:30:34 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://yoni-Lenovo-Z40-70:8088/proxy/application_1461971181442_0005/
16/04/30 20:30:34 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1461971181442_0005
16/04/30 20:30:41 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1461971181442_0005 running in uber mode : false
16/04/30 20:30:41 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
16/04/30 20:30:46 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 0%
16/04/30 20:30:51 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 100%
16/04/30 20:30:52 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1461971181442_0005 completed successfully
16/04/30 20:30:52 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 49
    File System Counters
        FILE: Number of bytes read=6
        FILE: Number of bytes written=211511
        FILE: Number of read operations=0
        FILE: Number of large read operations=0
        FILE: Number of write operations=0
        HDFS: Number of bytes read=170
        HDFS: Number of bytes written=86
        HDFS: Number of read operations=6
        HDFS: Number of large read operations=0
        HDFS: Number of write operations=2
    Job Counters 
        Launched map tasks=1
        Launched reduce tasks=1
        Data-local map tasks=1
        Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=2923
        Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=2526
        Total time spent by all map tasks (ms)=2923
        Total time spent by all reduce tasks (ms)=2526
        Total vcore-seconds taken by all map tasks=2923
        Total vcore-seconds taken by all reduce tasks=2526
        Total megabyte-seconds taken by all map tasks=2993152
        Total megabyte-seconds taken by all reduce tasks=2586624
    Map-Reduce Framework
        Map input records=1
        Map output records=0
        Map output bytes=0
        Map output materialized bytes=6
        Input split bytes=116
        Combine input records=0
        Combine output records=0
        Reduce input groups=0
        Reduce shuffle bytes=6
        Reduce input records=0
        Reduce output records=0
        Spilled Records=0
        Shuffled Maps =1
        Failed Shuffles=0
        Merged Map outputs=1
        GC time elapsed (ms)=166
        CPU time spent (ms)=1620
        Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=426713088
        Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=3818450944
        Total committed heap usage (bytes)=324009984
    Shuffle Errors
        BAD_ID=0
        CONNECTION=0
        IO_ERROR=0
        WRONG_LENGTH=0
        WRONG_MAP=0
        WRONG_REDUCE=0
    File Input Format Counters 
        Bytes Read=54
    File Output Format Counters 
        Bytes Written=86
16/04/30 20:30:52 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
16/04/30 20:30:52 WARN mapreduce.JobSubmitter: No job jar file set.  User classes may not be found. See Job or Job#setJar(String).
16/04/30 20:30:52 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
16/04/30 20:30:52 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:1
16/04/30 20:30:52 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1461971181442_0006
16/04/30 20:30:52 INFO mapred.YARNRunner: Job jar is not present. Not adding any jar to the list of resources.
16/04/30 20:30:52 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1461971181442_0006
16/04/30 20:30:52 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://yoni-Lenovo-Z40-70:8088/proxy/application_1461971181442_0006/
16/04/30 20:30:52 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1461971181442_0006
16/04/30 20:31:01 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1461971181442_0006 running in uber mode : false
16/04/30 20:31:01 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
16/04/30 20:31:07 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 0%
16/04/30 20:31:12 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 100%
16/04/30 20:31:13 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1461971181442_0006 completed successfully
16/04/30 20:31:13 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 49
    File System Counters
        FILE: Number of bytes read=6
        FILE: Number of bytes written=210495
        FILE: Number of read operations=0
        FILE: Number of large read operations=0
        FILE: Number of write operations=0
        HDFS: Number of bytes read=216
        HDFS: Number of bytes written=0
        HDFS: Number of read operations=7
        HDFS: Number of large read operations=0
        HDFS: Number of write operations=2
    Job Counters 
        Launched map tasks=1
        Launched reduce tasks=1
        Data-local map tasks=1
        Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=3739
        Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=3133
        Total time spent by all map tasks (ms)=3739
        Total time spent by all reduce tasks (ms)=3133
        Total vcore-seconds taken by all map tasks=3739
        Total vcore-seconds taken by all reduce tasks=3133
        Total megabyte-seconds taken by all map tasks=3828736
        Total megabyte-seconds taken by all reduce tasks=3208192
    Map-Reduce Framework
        Map input records=0
        Map output records=0
        Map output bytes=0
        Map output materialized bytes=6
        Input split bytes=130
        Combine input records=0
        Combine output records=0
        Reduce input groups=0
        Reduce shuffle bytes=6
        Reduce input records=0
        Reduce output records=0
        Spilled Records=0
        Shuffled Maps =1
        Failed Shuffles=0
        Merged Map outputs=1
        GC time elapsed (ms)=125
        CPU time spent (ms)=1010
        Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=427823104
        Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=3819626496
        Total committed heap usage (bytes)=324534272
    Shuffle Errors
        BAD_ID=0
        CONNECTION=0
        IO_ERROR=0
        WRONG_LENGTH=0
        WRONG_MAP=0
        WRONG_REDUCE=0
    File Input Format Counters 
        Bytes Read=86
    File Output Format Counters 
        Bytes Written=0
```

i am running the wordcount example that comes with the hadoop instalation

hadoop jar ./share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.6.0.jar grep /user/yoni/input /user/yoni/output101 'dfs[a-z.]+'

and the setup in the Pseudo distributed mode like in all the basic tutrials

Comment: I don't think `grep /user/yoni/input /user/yoni/output101 'dfs[a-z.]+'` is a valid argument to your jar. If it were, though, then if grep didn't return anything, then, yeah, you'd get an empty result

Comment: According to counters, your job received single record of input (`Map Input Records=1`) and found nothing matching given pattern (`Map output records=0`). That is why you get empty output (`Reduce output records=0`). `_SUCCESS` means that hadoop framework managed to complete your job and nothing more. Number of `part-xxxxx` files equals to number of reducers. Each of them may be empty if corresponding reducer didn't produce any output records.

Answer (score 0):

In this example, you should put all `xml` files under `hadoop-2.6.4/etc/hadoop` into `HDFS` folder named 'input' in proper user home directory, which is `yoni  here.

So first check your `HDFS` daemon process state by explore `http://localhost:50070`(by default).

Second, check your files' status by `bin/hdfs dfs -ls /user/yoni/input`, or `bin/hdfs fsck / -files -blocks`.

If all things going well, it should work.

[Hadoop MapReduce Next Generation - Setting up a Single Node Cluster](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.4/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html)